# One-way data binding from Angular singleton to any Component

Tags: angular, data-binding, singleton

I have this singleton service

```
@Injectable({
   providedIn: 'root'
})
export class WebSocketService {
   private channelObservable = new Subject<any>();
   private socket: any;
   public data: any;

   public connect() {
   // establish connection
   }

   public listenChannels(channels: string[]){
      // listen to given channels 
      // update local data
      // forward updated data through observable
      for (const channel of channels) {
         this.socket.on(channel, (data: any) => { 
            this.channelObservable.next(JSON.parse(data));
            // update local data with data coming from websocket
         }
      }
   }
}
```

which listens to a one or more websocket channels, and uses the incoming data to :

1. update a local data structure
2. send the data through an Observable (which is then subscribed by any Component interested in     the data)

Some context:

- the data structure is a JavaScript object, containing tens of thousands of key-value items;  when a new value comes  from the websocket for a key, that item is updated with the new value
- there can be up to hundreds of Components (not all visualized at the same time) each one presenting like 20-30 values from the global data structure

Is there any better performing way to bind the data to the each Component, instead of making each one subscribe to the Observable exposed by the service?

Is there any "extended" one-way data binding from the global data structure to each Component (not only children...)? Maybe holding the data in the root Component instead of a service?

Thanks,

Thomas

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I want you to notice that the right place for transfer data is the service, like yours. It's a singleton pattern, and yeah - that's ok. You have to keep your components in a proper hierarchy, use dumb and smart components, and pass the data between.

Angular architecture is strongly depends on change detection cicles. That's the reason you should prefer to pass `Observables` to any smart component needed the data.

*p.s. keep data in the root component is the bad idea.*

Comment: yeah, I know this is the orthodox way in angular; but angular also offers data binding (like father to child), which implicitly implements a "change detection" mechanism; so I was wondering if the latter could be used instead, for better performances; in other words, what is the cost in terms of memory and CPU, of having a big number of components subscribing to an observable?

Comment: You have nothing wrong with it if use `shareReplay` pipe.

Comment: And if you want pass same data more than through one component deep - that's already bad architecture and need refactoring. Some cases can be met, but not more.

Comment: what if I just inject the `WebSocketService` in my Component as `wService`, then I use the wService.data variable in my component template. Would I get data binding for that variable?

Comment: yes, for sure, - but is better to not have public service in the component and do binding through component's class property